# How to access cookies in Views PHP Code filter?

Tags: views, location, cookies

I have a view that will display nearby locations.

The center coordinates would come from a cookie (lat,lng).

I am trying to get the cookie with $_COOKIE, but I get an error saying that it is not set.

How would i access that cookie and return in for a proximity filter i Views (Using the Location module)?

Answer (score 1):

Checked with the views php module.

[image]

Then i get the cookies stored.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with the $_SESSION variable, e.g.

```
$value = $_SESSION['something'];
```